# MD5 hashed database password in api properties file

Tags: postgresql, encryption, md5, java

I have a rest api which talks to Postgres, right now in the properties file of the api we are hardcoding the DB password.
so we thought when a user role is created in postgres we can use Md5 hash value(or any other encrypted value which should be decrypted by postgres) for the password...and we can use that value(hased value) in api property file instead of hardcoded one.

My question is can we use that Md5 hash value in api dev property file and when the password is sent over network and tries to connect to postgres Will it (postgres) decrypt to actual password and allows the user to connect to DB without authentication failed?????

Comment: 'hash' != 'encryption'.  It is not possible to "decrypt" a "hashed" value.  Finally, to perform encryption and decryption you need a key.  So if you were to encrypt the password, you would need to have the key to decrypt it.

Comment: correct me if im wrong ...so you mean to say that i cannot update the config/property file with encrypted/hashed value for storing database password which is used by the api to connect to postgres database...i was concerened as i have to send the hardcoded value of the database password over network...we are using SSL though..      other question even if  i encrypt and send the database password over network and try to connect to postgres database ,how the postgres will decrypt the password???

Comment: when i have gone through the postgres reference postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-createuser.html it says "-E --encrypted Encrypts the user's password stored in the database. If not specified, the default password behavior is used." Can i use this encrypted password in my property file???

Comment: The principle of using hashes for passwords is that the client hashes the input and sends it to the server, which compares it to the stored hash. No decryption is performed. It's really quite pointless unless it's combined with some different random data each time, since the hash then serves as a substitute for the password and you don't have to know the original password. PostgreSQL uses a fixed salt when you store hashed passwords in the DB, so the protocol is quite weak and susceptible to replay attacks. Use SSL.

Comment: @CraigRinger so what the role of Md5 if it is just the substitute for the password...i mean if someone sniffs packets and got the hashed or clear-text password ...its good enough to connect to Database rt??correct me if im wrong

Comment: I was wrong when I suggested the PostgreSQL protocol was prone to replay attacks with `md5` mode. It uses a second layer of hashing with a random per-session salt to protect against that. So it's much better than using `password` mode.

Comment: so you mean if we use md5 mode ,the jdbc uses second layer of hashing with a random per-session salt to protect against that when i connect to postgres from my application???

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: you can't store the hashed password in a properties file and use it to authenticate unless the client application can recognise that it's pre-hashed and avoid the second hashing pass.

If the client library *does* recognise pre-hashed passwords (libpq doesn't), the hashed password can be used as a proxy for the real password. You don't need to know the real password if you know the hash. this means it's also no more secure to store the hashed password in the properties file than it is to store the original password.

The password is salted and hashed again before being sent on the wire so you can't  sniff what you see on the wire and use that to authenticate.

---

Looking at the source code, `sendAuthRequest` in `src/backend/libpq/auth.c`:

```
/* Add the salt for encrypted passwords. */
if (areq == AUTH_REQ_MD5)
    pq_sendbytes(&buf, port->md5Salt, 4);
```

`port` is `struct Port` in `src/include/libpq/libpq-be.h`, which has:

```
char        md5Salt[4];     /* Password salt */
```

This is set by `ConnCreate` in `src/backend/postmaster/postmaster.c`:

```
    /*
     * Precompute password salt values to use for this connection. It's
     * slightly annoying to do this long in advance of knowing whether we'll
     * need 'em or not, but we must do the random() calls before we fork, not
     * after.  Else the postmaster's random sequence won't get advanced, and
     * all backends would end up using the same salt...
     */
    RandomSalt(port->md5Salt);
```

Now, passwords are verified in `md5_crypt_verify` in `src/backend/libpq/crypt.c`. There we see that passwords already stored as md5 are hashed again with the session salt:

```
        if (isMD5(shadow_pass))
        {
            /* stored password already encrypted, only do salt */
            if (!pg_md5_encrypt(shadow_pass + strlen("md5"),
                                port->md5Salt,
                                sizeof(port->md5Salt), crypt_pwd))
            {
                pfree(crypt_pwd);
                return STATUS_ERROR;
            }
        }
```

Thus the hashed password sent on the wire is protected against replay attacks by the session salt.

---

Whether the client app can recognise a pre-hashed password and the format it expects them to be in depends on the client library.

According to `pg_password_sendauth` in `src/interfaces/libpq/fe-auth.c` the libpq front-end doesn't seem to check for pre-hashed password input. Other clients may vary.

Comment: sorry im bit confused...so where the md5 password will be created first ??in postgres (while creating user by enabling md5 auth-mode) ??? or client has to create a salt for the password and generate Md5 hashed password and use the same in postgres while creating the user????    and   which value(password/hashed password) i have to place in property file which is used by jdbc connection to connect to postgres..and wat is this pre-hashed means is it the hashed password  which is created in postgress ,and finally is the above code is in postgres???

Comment: @shiv455 when you `ALTER USER theusername ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'mypass'` the password is hashed with a salt, then both hash and salt are stored in the `pg_authid` table. To make a JDBC connection *just use the password*. Forget about hashing etc. Stop worrying about it. Store. The. Plain. Text. Password. In. The. Properties. File. PgJDBC and PostgreSQL deal with the hashing etc.

Comment: So in this case the password authentication mode should be password or md5 if it is password mode and still postgres takes care of md5 hashing while sending over wire then wat the md5 mode is for??? and sorry the whole purpose of this thread is i do not want to use the plain text password in the property file,then when asked for using encrypted/hashed password in the property file ..all the above discussion happened...correct me if im wrong...

Comment: You have to use plain text in the properties file. You don't get a choice. The purpose of `md5` mode in PostgreSQL is that (a) PostgreSQL doesn't have to store the original password text in the database, which means if the DB is stolen the plaintext can't be recovered and used to try that password on other services; and (b) the exchange of passwords on the network is further hashed and salted to protect against replay attacks. So `md5` authentication mode is better, but does not let you avoid storing a plaintext password on the client side.

Comment: actually we dont want to expose the plain text password in property file when deployed in production thats where my point of storing encrypted password question raised...so you mean to say there is no way i can connect to postgres with encrypted password ??? and as you said when i use ALTER USER theusername ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'mypass'  the password which is stored in pg_authid table i cannot use in property file to connect....if yes its just substitute of the plain password as there is no decryption happens in postgres...trying to make myself clear

Comment: You have to store the plaintext password in the properties file. The JDBC driver hashes it before sending to the server. You cannot substitute the hashed password from `pg_authid`. Even if you could, it would be pointless because that would then *be* the password, usable everywhere that the original password could be used, so you would not gain any security. You are wasting your time. You have to store the password in the properties file. Whatever you store has to let you connect. So if stolen it lets others connect.

Comment: If you're really concerned you need to (a) study authentication protocols/handshakes and HMAC, and (b) look into using a host trust mechanism like Kerberos or key trust like a client certificate with a hardware crypto offload so you have an un-stealable credential. Doing this is complicated. You will need to study a lot and learn a lot more. Simply store the plaintext in the properties file. (I will not reply again).

Comment: Read about authentication protocols, hashing and salting vs encryption, etc.

Comment: Thanks craig for your detailed explanation i think the only way for me to secure the password @ my application level i need to store encrypted password in property file and decrypt it before making the JDBC connection(using some encrypt/decrypt algorithms) in this way the password which is present in property file is secure ...

Comment: @shiv455 No, you just move the weakness to the decryption key for the password, which you have to store somewhere. Unless you use a crypto offload device like a USB crypto key or smart card, in which case you might as well use it directly for a client certificate for PostgreSQL authentication. You are not thinking this through. At some level a secret sufficient to authenticate to the database must be stored somewhere. Unless you plan to enter the properties decryption key each time you start the app - and even then it's stored in memory. Don't reinvent the wheel. Read or hire someone.

Comment: so you mean if we use md5 mode ,the jdbc uses second layer of hashing with a random per-session salt to protect against that when i connect to postgres from my application???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96680/discussion-between-shiv455-and-craig-ringer).

Comment: I'm not going to engage in chat. I've said all I can. If you aren't convinced you really need to do some reading about authentication protocols, application security, hash and salt vs encryption etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear - `md5` hashing is **not** encryption.

> 19.3.2. Password authentication
>
> The password-based authentication methods are **md5** and **password**. These
>   methods operate similarly except for the way that the password is sent
>   across the connection, **namely MD5-hashed and clear-text respectively**.
>
> If you are at all concerned about password "sniffing" attacks then md5
>   is preferred. Plain password should always be avoided if possible.
>   However, md5 cannot be used with the db_user_namespace feature. If the
>   connection is protected by SSL encryption then password can be used
>   safely (though SSL certificate authentication might be a better choice
>   if one is depending on using SSL).
>
> PostgreSQL database passwords are separate from operating system user
>   passwords. The password for each database user is stored in the
>   pg_authid system catalog. Passwords can be managed with the SQL
>   commands CREATE USER and ALTER USER, e.g., CREATE USER foo WITH
>   PASSWORD 'secret'. If no password has been set up for a user, the
>   stored password is null and password authentication will always fail
>   for that user.

If you configure your **[Postgres client authentication file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)** (`pg_hba.conf`) for `md5` **[password-based authentication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/auth-methods.html)**, you don't need to explicitly use md5() function to keep database password in your property file.

For encrypting purposes - you can configure database connection to work over SSL. Please check  [**Secure TCP/IP Connections with SSL**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ssl-tcp.html).

Comment: As per your 1st suggestion,you mean still i have to store the database password as plain text in the property file even i enable md5 password-based authentication in postgres....if yes the password is sent as plain text over network rt...we are using SSL though..

Comment: password will be `md5`-hashed not plain text when it's sent over - but java `.properties` file will contain just plain text; if you use `password` option in `pg_hba` - it will be plain text @shiv455

Comment: trying to understand--- even if i have plain text password in api property file it will sent as md5 hashed value(through network) if i choose md5 password-based authentication in postgres???   how does api or network will know to send as md5 hashed value if the authentication mode is set in postgres...or irrespective of the authentication mode set in postgres the password will be sent as Md5 hashed over network???

Comment: please read the documentation @shiv455 i highlighted the quote from there

Comment: when  i have gone through the postgres reference http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-createuser.html   it says           "-E
--encrypted
Encrypts the user's password stored in the database. If not specified, the default password behavior is used."       Can i use this encrypted password in my property file???

Comment: @shiv455 It *isn't encrypted*. It's a hash of the password. Whether you can use it as-is depends on the client application and whether it supports recognising pre-hashed passwords. But really, it's quite pointless because if you *can* use the hashed password then the hash actually *is* the password; you don't need to know the original hash input to connect, so there's no security gain from using just the hash. Whatever problem you are attempting to solve, you're barking up the wrong tree here.

Comment: @CraigRinger Thanks for your explanation...So you are suggesting to use SSL(and configure md5 authentication in postgress) and use plain text password in api property file which then transforms to md5 hash format when sent over the network and will be able to connect to postgres database...correct me if im wrong    ,actually im using jdbc template to connect to postgres and we are storing the hardcode password in the api property/config file

Comment: Yes, that's right. If you think about it, whatever you put in the properties file must be enough to connect to PostgreSQL. So if you could put the hash in the properties file and use that to connect to PostgreSQL, the hash would be just as useful to steal as the original password.

Comment: correct, if connection is encrypted via SSL you can use plain `password` @shiv455

Comment: so there is no benefit of using md5(auth-mode) if SSL is in place is it???please correct me if im wrong

Comment: well, SSL is preferable; `md5` will be a solution if somebody sniffing packets and instead of plain text he will get a hash (I think it even has a salt),which  can be cracked with dictionary or brute force attack anyways.@shiv455

Comment: @Dimitry if somebody sniffung packets and gets hash instead of plain text as you said earlier its just replacement of password...so he can connect to the database anyways right ??correct me if im wrong

Comment: so what is the point of MD5 mode in postgres,trying to understand how different it is from clear-text and how to use it in client side to connect to Database

Comment: "Yes, using MD5 is safe. When a client wants to authenticate, the server sends a random salt value. The client uses that value, along with the password to generate a MD5 hash. Because a random salt is used, an attacker can not use a dictionary attack. Also, because the salt is changed each time a client authenticates, this is no ability to replay old authentication requests."   from http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41064/is-postgres-password-based-authentication-secure          ....want to understand how this works from clients perspective